# Recording thoughts without being worried about having to think fast to come up with the next thing to say

Tags: recording

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sound Recording Application that Starts/Stops Automatically](https://superuser.com/questions/69587/sound-recording-application-that-starts-stops-automatically)

I want the following technology: I record my thoughts. And then automatically the space where I don't say anything (because I am thinking) is deleted. How can this be done?

In other words I like to put my ideas about how to better my life in recording because it's faster than typing. But of course outlining is the best way to organize your life. But outlines can get out of control too and hard to read if there are no coloring in it like you see on codes of computer programming languages.

Anyway, is there some kind of thnig within Garageband or Audacity that allows you to autaomatically cut off the part where you don't say anything in the receording? Or, if there is about 10 seconds of silence in midst of your talking because you had to search for words and form a sentence in your head first, could that 10 seconds be reduced to 1 second of break?

And what is your way of solving problems in your life? Do you use a particular outlining software?

Comment: I think it's called "voice-activated recording".

Answer (score 2):

The word your looking for is "sound activated" it was in audacity since 1.3.6 acording to the web.  "sound activation" is what it says . It tries to record when there is a signal , and cuts out eventually when there is no signal. Every small digital and even tape handy recorder has had it in it.  I find it can clip stuff off, and waits to long after stopping most the time, on most of the devices. A "foot pedal" :-) is a better idea.  To often to many other noises here will set the sound activations off.

If you want to be restricted to voice, might try a "Speech to text" program instead. Something like dragon naturally speaking, it goes all stupid if it just hears noises, or I start mumbling. It is also faster to read text than it is to listen to a recording?

To solve problems in my life I avoid memorisation and instead try and find the logic and stereotype things. AKA things are simple, if you toss out all the complexity that makes them fail :-)